# InAppSettingsKit IASKButtonSpecifier not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, inappsettingskit

Help please! For two days I try to get this working. I integrated IASK with a TableViewController and IASKAppSettingsViewController as custom class. I followed the Sample App, but using a Storyboard and I inserted the ARC codes. 
I am also using IASK CustomSubviewController in my .plist, which worked from the very beginning without problems. None of the button works works, except a UI button that I added to the TableViewController.  This is the code. Thanks for any hints.
In  h:

```
- (void)settingsViewController:(IASKAppSettingsViewController*)sender   
buttonTappedForSpecifier:(IASKSpecifier*)specifier;
```

In m:

```
- (void)settingsViewController:(IASKAppSettingsViewController*)sender       
buttonTappedForSpecifier:           

(IASKSpecifier*)specifier {
if ([specifier.key isEqualToString:@"saveButton"]) {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Exit Settings" 
 message:@"Did you enter all settings?"     
 delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
    [alert show]       
}
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
if (buttonIndex == 1) { 

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    exit(0);
}}
```

Thats from my Root~iphone.inApp.plist:

```
<dict>
        <key>Key</key>
        <string>saveButton</string>
        <key>Title</key>
        <string>Save all settings</string>
        <key>Type</key>
        <string>IASKButtonSpecifier</string>
</dict>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it looks strange"? Please post a screenshot.

Comment: Thank you! The UI Button that is working is a standard UI Button, which is sitting at the bottom of the screen. What I wanted is the IASK Button to work, which is sitting in between the other buttons and fields. Unfortunately I can't post a screen shot, but hope I made myself clear.

Comment: No I don't understand what the problem is. Please post a screenshot or sample project.

Comment: I had found a workaround, but ran into another problem with the Kit when I wanted to change something in the Root~iphone.inApp.plist. I added a new textfield specifier, but the change doesn't reflect in the IASK settings view, only the Settings.app has changed. I have only these two files, Root.plist and Root~iphone.inApp.plist, in my bundle. This might be also the reason why the ButtonSpecifier dont work.

Comment: and I deleted my app several times. The IASK settings view remains the same.

Comment: Are you saying that a change in `Settings.bundle/Root~iphone.inApp.plist` was not reflected in IASK but in the Settings.app? That would be more than weird. If you provide a sample project, I can look into it.